# Right and left differentiability

Tags: real-analysis

**Suppose $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R $ is differentiable on (a,b) and continuous on [a,b]. Does it follow that $f$ is right-differentiable at $a$ and left-differentiable at $b$?**

I guess it does not follow since $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R $ can be  differentiable at a point, call it $ c \in (a,b)$ but not at the end points since the interval is open.

Is it right? If so, how do i formally prove?

Thanks!

Comment: Think of square roots...

Comment: am I assuming right?

Comment: Yes yes you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function given by
$$f(x)=\cases{x\cos(1/x)&if $0<x\le1$\cr 0&if $x=0$.\cr}$$
It is clear that $f$ is continuous on $(0,1]$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$.  Moreover,
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=0$$
by the pinching theorem (sandwich theorem, squeeze theorem), so $f$ is also continuous at $0$ and the assumptions in your question are satisfied.  However, $f$ is not right-differentiable at $0$ since
$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\cos\Bigl(\frac1x\Bigr)$$
has no limit as $x\to0^+$.

Comment: Would it be still valid if $f$ is continuous on [0,1]?

Comment: In my example, $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Ok, i just saw that "...f is continuous on (0,1] ..." thanks!